# reactjs Failed prop type: Invalid prop `className` of type `object` supplied to `ForwardRef(IconButton)`, expected `string`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a code from reactjs that is working but, what i mean by woring because it does what it needs, in this case it expand and close when the button is close.

i have an error from the console

```
Failed prop type: Invalid prop `className` of type `object` supplied to `ForwardRef(IconButton)`, expected `string`.
    in ForwardRef(IconButton) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(IconButton)))
```

while my code is simple, i just want to add material ui expander

```
  const { schedule, classes, onClick, deleteScd, visible } = props;
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);

 const handleExpandClick = (e) => {
    // setExpanded(!expanded);
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation();
    if(!expanded){
      setExpanded(true);
    }else{
      setExpanded(false);
    }
    console.log(expanded)
  };

    <Draggable>
      <Card className={classes.root} >
          <CardActions disableSpacing  className={classes.cardExpand } onClick={onClick} >
          <Box className={classes.head} >
            <Typography variant="h5" className={classes.title}>
              {title}
            </Typography>
            <Typography className={classes.timezone} color="textSecondary">
              {timezone}
            </Typography>
          </Box>
          <IconButton
            className={classes.expand, {
              [classes.expandOpen]: expanded,
            }}
            onClick={handleExpandClick}
            aria-expanded={expanded}
            aria-label="show more"
          >
            <ExpandMoreIcon className={classes.expandIcon} />
          </IconButton>
          </CardActions>
        <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
          <Card className={classes.root} variant="outlined">
            <CardContent style={{ padding: "10px 3px 3px 3px" }}>
              

              Content

              
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </Collapse>
      </Card>
   </Draggable>
```

i want to fix this because i have another problems with my ref

Answer (score 2):

The `className` prop of the `IconButton` component must receive a string value (as the prop type warning states). You could use a ternary expression to apply a class only when your view is expanded, something like `className={expanded ? classes.expandOpen : ''}`.

Comment: it only makes it on loop, or maybe it happens because of another code  ?

Comment: I'm not following, can you elaborate?